# Need help on Javascript prototype functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, prototypejs

```
function Weekday (name, traffic) {
this.name = name;
this.traffic = traffic;
}

function mostPopularDays(week) { 
week = [];
week.push(this.name, this.traffic);
if(week.length > 1){
    return week;
}else if(week.length === null || week === []){
    return null;
}else {
    return week[0];
}
}

var mon = new Weekday("Monday", 200);
mostPopularDays(mon);
```

/**
 * Determines which day of the week had the most nnumber of people visiting the
 * pet store. If more than one day of the week has the same, highest amount of
 * traffic, an array containing the days (in any order) should be returned.
 * (ex. ["Wednesday", "Thursday"]). If the input is null or an empty array, the function
 * should return null.
 * @param week an array of Weekday objects
 * @return a string containing the name of the most popular day of the week if there is only one most popular day, and an array of the strings containing the names of the most popular days if there are more than one that are most popular
 */

I've been seriously learning Javascript for over 2 weeks now then I took this course in EDx and apparently,  still can't solve this kind of problem. The code above is my own code and I know its wrong(except the Weekday function). A help would be gladly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `mostPopularDays` function never actually uses the provided argument as it is replaced on the first line.

```
function mostPopularDays(week) { 
week = [];
```

Then there is an out of context `this`, the function `mostPopularDays` is not related in any way to the `WeekDay`, so the `this` you are referring to is actually the `mostPopularDays` function itself and not the intended `WeekDay` you provided.

From what I understand from the text describing the assignment there should be more than one argument to `mostPopularDays` in order to filter out the most most popular ones ("@param week an array of Weekday objects").

So, your TODO-list is as follows:

- rename the argument to `mostPopularDays` to represent the input to be an array of `WeekDay` (I'd use `weeks` (+s) or `weekList`)
- there is no need to push anything into the array from within `mostPopularDays`.
- there is no use for `this` within `mostPopularDays`, you want to be referring to an item in the provided array of `WeekDay` objects

I don't known which ways of traversing an array your course had covered so far, there are several:

- `for (var i = 0; i < weekList.length; ++i) { ... }`
- `weekList.forEach(function(week) { ... })`
- (If you've already covered the reducing and sorting of arrays, you may want to look into those, as that would be my preferred choice)

Answer (score 0):

For test you should create objects(days) and array of objects.

Then sort objects and check if there is more than one day you should return.

I also made a condition to give full answer if there is more than one day with highest traffic.

```js
var mon = new Weekday('Monday', 5);
var tue = new Weekday('Tuesday', 3);
var wed = new Weekday('Wednesday',8);
var thu = new Weekday('Thursday', 5);
var fri = new Weekday('Friday', 14);
var sat = new Weekday('Saturday', 14 );
var sun = new Weekday('Sunday', 0);

var weekDays = [mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun];

function mostPopularDays(week) {
    week.sort(compare);
    var mostPopularDay = [];
    var mostPopularDayValue = week[0].traffic;

    week.forEach(day => {
        if(day.traffic == mostPopularDayValue){
            mostPopularDay.push(day.name);
        }
    });

    if(mostPopularDay.length>1){
        console.log('The most popular days are: '+ mostPopularDay);
    } else{
        console.log('The most popular day is '+ mostPopularDay);
    }    
}
function compare(a,b) {
    if (a.traffic < b.traffic)
      return 1;
    if (a.traffic > b.traffic)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }
function Weekday (name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
mostPopularDays(weekDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and you can understand quickly.

```
function mostPopularDays(week) {
    if(week.length === 0){
        return null;
    }
    var maxArray = [];
    var max = '';
    for(i=0; i < week.length; i++){
        if(week[i].traffic === max){
            maxArray.push(week[i].name);
        }else if(week[i].traffic > max){
            maxArray = [];
            maxArray.push(week[i].name);
            max = week[i].traffic;
        };
    }
    if(maxArray.length === 1){
        return maxArray[0];
    } else {
        return maxArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation of the code would be helpful - Welcome to Stack Overflow :)